# How can i run a query with the loop to get the day wise data in mongodb using python

Tags: python, pandas, mongodb, pymongo

I have a MongoDB Query which gives me the data of the users who viewed how many products in a day (basically a count of there views). Below is the query

```
pipeline = [
    {
        '$match':{
            "ts":{'$gte': 1596997800000 , '$lt': 1597084200000},
            "Event_Name":'Content_Impression'
        }
    },
    {
        '$group':{
            '_id':'$User_Id',
            'count':{'$sum':1}
        }
    }
]

res = product_view.aggregate(pipeline)
df = pd.DataFrame(list(res))
df.head()
```

below is the result of the above query.

```
+-----+-------+
| _id | count |
+-----+-------+
|  12 |    50 |
|  52 |    70 |
| 100 |   100 |
| 473 |    43 |
| 474 |    72 |
+-----+-------+
```

I would want to run the same query multiple times to get the data for multiple days. Is there a way I could run a single query in a loop to return me every days data.

My expectation is something like this below

```
+-----+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| _id | 10/08/20 | 11/08/20 | 12/08/20 | 13/08/20 | 14/08/20 |
+-----+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|  12 |       50 |      125 |          |          |       66 |
|  52 |       70 |      142 |      135 |          |          |
| 100 |      100 |          |          |       13 |          |
| 473 |       43 |          |       93 |          |      200 |
| 474 |       72 |      160 |      129 |          |      180 |
+-----+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Please let me know if there is an option to do this using python and pymongo.
Thanks in advance

Comment: How is the field `ts` stored? as a number or a date?

Comment: It's in number, Its an epoch date basically.

Answer (score 0):

If your version of mongodb is higher than 4.0, you can even do it in one request.

With [$toDate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/), you can convert your ts to a date format.

And then you can for example group by user and by date like this :

```
{
    $project: {
        month: {$month: "$createdAt"},
        day: {$dayOfMonth: "$createdAt"},
        year: {$year: "$createdAt"}
    }
},
{
        '$group':{
            '_id':{User_Id:'$User_Id', month: "$month", day: "$day", year: "$year"},
            'User_Id':{$first:'$User_Id'},
            'count':{'$sum':1}
        }
}
```

If you want to do it with a for loop, you can do something like this :

```
# init the date start
day = arrow.get("2020-01-01")

# loop through 100 days
for i in range(0, 100):
    # create a new pipeline with the day variable
    pipeline = [
        {
            '$match': {
                "ts": {'$gte': day.timestamp, '$lt': day.ceil('day').timestamp},
                "Event_Name": 'Content_Impression'
            }
        },
        {
            '$group': {
                '_id': '$User_Id',
                'count': {'$sum': 1}
            }
        }
    ]

    # run here the query and add it to your result object
    
    # Add a day
    day.shift(days=1)
```

I'm using the package arrow to manipulate the dates, because I'm used to it. But you can do the same with Datetime.